# PHP: execute function upon clicking a button

Tags: javascript, php, crud

I am building a PHP & mySQLi CRUD app.

Inside a functions.php file I have a function that takes care of *deleting individual users*:

```
function delte_single_user() {
 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    global $con;
    $user_id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE * FROM `users` WHERE `id`= " . (int)$user_id . ";";
    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
 }
}
```

In the file that displays the users, I have the CRUD "buttons":

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a title="View user" href="view_user.php?id=<?php echo $arr['id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
    <li><a title="Delete user" onclick="delte_single_user()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I am trying to fire the `delte_single_user()` upon clicking the delete button, JavaScript style (I am new to PHP but I have significant experience JavaScript). But it does not work.

So, what is PHP's closest alternative to my use of `delte_single_user()`?

NOTE: I am trying to avoid creating a delete_user.php fie as it would not be useful.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Gonna need to use **Ajax**, friend. Look up some tutorials on it :)

Comment: @GROVER: could you provide links to the best you know? Thank you!

Comment: @GROVER: Well, I did use Ajax (and a nice Bootstrap modal), but that still does not solve the problem: calling a function from functions.php instead of loading a delete.php page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a PHP function from JS directly.

You need to make an ajax call or redirect to the PHP script that handles the delete.

The same as you are doing with linking to the `view_user.php` script.

You could create a new script called `delete_user.php` and pass it the id of the user using GET. Inside this script put the function above and call it.

```
<a title="Delete user" href="delete_user.php?id=SOME_ID">DELETE</a>
```

EDIT:

Consider having a `user.php` script that handles everything user related. like:

```
user.php?action=view&id=USER_ID
user.php?action=delete&id=USER_ID
```

This way you have a single file, and in `user.php` you could do:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete') {
    // check id
    // delete the user AND redirect the user back (if not using ajax)
} elseif (/* check if action=view */) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid creating a delete_user.php fie. I don't now what I could out in it. It is a different story with the view_user.php (it displays user data in  a ascetically adequate manner which is also useful).

Comment: You need to call a php script regardless of what you're doing. Calling the `functions.php` file directly is bad design. Edited my answer to use a single php script.

Comment: And BTW, you don't need to display anything in delete_user.php. Either call it through AJAX or if you use an `<a>` tag then just redirect the user back to  the previous page using: `header('Location: page.php')`